# USB Microphone quiet

Tags: microphone

I have been trying anything that I can to get the recording volume from a USB Microphone to increase. You can talk beside it and it won't pick up your voice unless you speak very close to the mic. The microphone does work having tested it on a computer.

I have tried alsamixer and icreased the gain to max, but still not loud enough.

Is there a way to increase this gain even further?

This is rather lacking in detail, but I have looked through nearly every single thread on this matter and can't find anything that works.

Thank you.

Comment: your post contains conflicting information .... `won't pick up anything` or `still not loud enough` .... which is it? ... no sound or low sound? .... please edit your question ...  do not use comments because the question will still be the same

Comment: @Alexander Osborne, (1)  perhaps you do not use the type of mic that suits you best.  You might like to read my answer to the following question for more details: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/100975/ugreen-usb-soundcard-microphone-in-fail-but-speaker-out-work, (2) Perhaps the pre amplifier of your USB sound card is not sensitive enough, (3) My get around is to use a power amp  at the output.